# Antd Select: Pre-render listbox node before user interacts with the component

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, accessibility, antd, wai-aria

I am using antd Select component, but i keep getting this error in my accessibility report about invalid aria-* attributes. It is caused because for some unknown reason antd renders the dom node with [role="listbox"] which contains the options after you first interact with the component. Is there some way to pre-render the list before the user interacts with the select, which i think would be the normal thing to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility reports always need some human interpretation of the warnings and errors.

I’m assuming the error here as about the `listbox` role not owning `option` elements.

The only information that assistive technology might relay to users, which depends on the options to be present on focus, is the number of options available.

But to my knowledge, the current AT out there doesn’t even do that for `<select>` elements. Only once you navigate the list, the number is exposed.

If this is not the case, and you know for a fact that the options get added with the right roles once the listbox opens, and that other accessibility requirements are fulfilled, you can simply ignore that error.